# Call to undefined method stdClass::delete() Laravel 5.3

Tags: database, laravel

I have a table with 2 primary keys user_id, event_id. I want to remove a row of specific event and uer id, however I get this error (see picture):

```
$eventUser=DB::table('eventuser')->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
                ->where('event_id', '=', $eventId)
                ->first();
$eventUser->delete();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Query Builder, you don't have access to the Eloquent delete method. Instead, you can delete a record by including it in your query:

```
DB::table('eventuser')->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
                ->where('event_id', '=', $eventId)
                ->delete();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#deletes)

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be incorrect. You need to pass an array of conditions to the `where` function, like this:

```
$eventUser=DB::table('eventuser')->where([
    ['user_id', '=', $userId],
    ['event_id', '=', $eventId]
])->first();

$eventUser->delete();
```